# Window application what written in c# by myself not appearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Today I run into a strange error.
When I start my program without Visual studio 2010 Express, start to running, but the gui not appear, and inpossible do stop it in task managger.
But if I run it in Visual studio, it work without any problem.
It do it with my all c# program,even what I write years before, but not any other program.
Tried to check, if a virus do it, but it can't find anything.

Operting system is Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be antivirus who stops execution of your application. Try to turn off it.

Comment: Oh it's working. I always forget that, the antivirus only bother my programs but not the virus.

Comment: @Bady I bet you use Avast, There has a lot of questions recently with the same problem as you and Avast has always been the AV. Something they did is causing basic .NET programs to be flagged as viruses for them.

Comment: I usually know, the avast is fault, but now even can't stop the program,  and I was think it was different. (it still show the programs in the task manager, and I still can't stop it) Sometimes My c++ programs detected as a virus, because I read some data from a vectors and write it into a file. It a little bit annoying, but I don't know better antivirus. :(